# Docker Container Cannot Connect to Host Services, Receiving 400 Error

Tags: javascript, python, docker, docker-compose

I'm encountering a connectivity issue within my Docker setup, and I'm seeking some guidance on how to resolve it. I have a Docker Compose configuration with multiple services, and one of these services needs to communicate with a service on the host machine. However, I'm consistently getting a 400 error when attempting to do so, despite the fact that it works fine when I test it using Postman from the host machine.

Here's my Docker Compose file:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
    db:
        container_name: mobydq-db-og
        restart: always
        image: mobydq-db
        build:
            context: ./db
        volumes:
            - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        env_file:
            - ./.env

    graphql:
        container_name: mobydq-graphql-og
        restart: always
        image: mobydq-graphql
        build:
            context: ./graphql
        volumes:
            - //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        env_file:
            - ./.env
        depends_on:
            - db

    app:
        container_name: mobydq-app-og
        restart: always
        image: mobydq-app
        build:
            context: ./app
        env_file:
            - ./.env
        depends_on:
            - graphql
        command: ["prod"]

    nginx:
        container_name: mobydq-nginx-og
        restart: always
        image: nginx:alpine
        volumes:
            - ./nginx/config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
            - ./nginx/config/cert.pem:/etc/nginx/cert.pem
            - ./nginx/config/key.pem:/etc/nginx/key.pem
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        depends_on:
            - graphql

    scripts:
        container_name: mobydq-scripts-og
        restart: always
        image: mobydq-scripts
        build:
            context: ./scripts
            args:
                - MAIL_HOST=${MAIL_HOST}
                - MAIL_PORT=${MAIL_PORT}
                - MAIL_SENDER=${MAIL_SENDER}
                - MAIL_PASSWORD=${MAIL_PASSWORD}
                - MAIL_BASE_URL=${MAIL_BASE_URL}
        env_file:
            - ./.env
        depends_on:
            - graphql
    networks:
    default:
        name: mobydq_network

    volumes:
      db:
```

I have already tried to add an extra_hosts directive in my mobydq-scripts-og service, mapping host.docker.internal to host-gateway. However, this didn't resolve the issue.

I also tried creating a custom bridge network named mobydq_network, and specifying this network for the services that need access to the host machine. Still, the issue persists.

this is the python code in scripts that contacts the api

```
def get_email_settings(authorization: str):
"""Retrieve e-mail settings from API."""
try:
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {authorization}',}
    response = 
    requests.get("https://host.docker.internal:44358/api/services/app/TenantSettings/
    GetAllSettings", headers=headers, verify=False)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()['result']['email']
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as error:
    error_message = f"HTTP error occurred: {error}"
    log.error(error_message)
except Exception as error: # pylint: disable=broad-except
    error_message = f"An error occurred: {error}"
    log.error(error_message)
```

and this is the code in mobydq plugin responsible for starting a scripts container

```
  // Create custom resolver to execute batch of indicators
  const runExecuteBatchContainer = () => {
      return {
        // Get batch id from the database
        requires: {
            childColumns: [{ column: "id", alias: "$batch_id" }],
        },
        async resolve(resolve, _source, _args, _context, _resolveInfo) {
            // Let resolver execute against database
            const result = await resolve();

            // Capture parameters to run Docker container
            const authorization = _context.authorization;
            const batchId = result.data.$batch_id;

            // Instantiate Docker
            var Docker = require("dockerode");
            var docker = new Docker({ socketPath: "/var/run/docker.sock" });

            // Run Docker container
            docker.run(
                "mobydq-scripts",
                ["python", "run.py", authorization, "execute_batch", batchId.toString()],
                process.stdout,
                { name: "mobydq-batch-" + batchId, HostConfig: { AutoRemove: true, 
            NetworkMode: "mobydq_network" } },
                function(err, data, container) {
                    // Do nothing
                }
            );

            return result;
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you using? If it's Linux `host.docker.internal` only works if you are using [Docker Desktop](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/ubuntu/). Then you can try to add this to your docker-compose

```
extra_hosts:
   - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

Comment: I'm on windows and keep getting 400 with host.docker.internal